# Rsync with only one folder

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I want to rsync my data to other vps.

My 1st vps data is located in MERLIN directory,here is the path - `/home/USERNAME/create/MERLIN`

there are other folders and sub folders in USERNAME and create directory which I dont want to make backup.

My remote location of vps is - `/home/USERNAME/similar/backup` (I want to make my backup here)

```
rsync -r -a -e SSH remoteuser(user of my 1st vps)@remote_host(my 1st vps):/home/USERNAME/create/MERLIN /home/USERNAME/similar/backup
```

But it syncs all other directories and sub directories apart from MERLIN directory and it's contents. How can I just make backup of only MERLIN and it's contents.

Comment: When you say "it syncs all other directories and sub directories", do you mean subdirectories in `MERLIN`? or these "other folders and subfolders in `USERNAME` and `create` directory which you don't want to make backup"?

Comment: Yes exactly I want only Merlin and it's sub directories contents. And not the folders of USERNAME and create (they both have other files too). When I sync my back up directory of other vps have all files from /home /USERNAME/create/ too which I don't want. I want only Merlin and it's total contents.

Comment: Cannot replicate. In theory the tool should stay inside `MERLIN`. Omit the destination (so there is only one source and no destination) to make `rsync` list files that would be synced. Are files outside of `MERLIN` listed really? Pay attention to unquoted spaces in your actual command. If not sure, use `--dry-run` and `--verbose` just in case.

Comment: No my all files are inside MERLIN only. I am just begin to use rsync so not sure of the term what you are asking me to do.

Comment: Does `rsync -rae ssh --dry-run --verbose remoteuser@remote_host:/home/USERNAME/create/MERLIN` list files that are outside of `MERLIN`?

Comment: No they list only the files of folder MERLIN.

Comment: In this case I can see no way your `rsync` can process other files. Maybe unless your actual string in place of `/home/USERNAME/similar/backup` contains an unquoted space or something that makes the shell treat it as two (or more) arguments, yet the last one points to the right place (relative path?); so `rsync` processes some *local* files you don't expect? Or maybe there are files in `backup` from your old erroneous tries? They survived because you don't use `--delete` with the current command. Anyway the command (as it is in the question body) does not process files outside of `MERLIN`.

Comment: I have got that running now. Thanks again. I successfully back up entire folder.